# React native locally Video file not loaded in Webview online and offline mode from local HTML file in iOS Release Build

Tags: html, ios, react-native, video, webview

I want to display video file in my webview form HTML. HTML is in local folder and my video file also in local folder.

My HTML located in my project as below structure
src-->html-->html-->demo.html

And my video file located at below structure
src-->html-->html-->images-->demo.mp4

in my HTML file i write code for video load as below

```
<video id="patientvideo" width="320" height="240" controls muted>
    <source src="images/demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And in my main screen in webview I am loading as below

```
let demoHtmlData = require('../../html/html/demo.html');

<WebView
    ref={ref => (webViewRef.current = ref)}
    source={demoHtmlData}
    styles={styles.mainContainer}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    onMessage={m => {
      onMessage(m);
    }}
  />
```

When i Run above code in debug mode it is working fine but when i make release build at that time video is not loaded and showing like as below

[image]

Any idea how can i solve this ?